# Can't connect this network , but USB 2.0 Wifi adapter connects

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, windows-8

I have problem with my Notebook's wifi. First of when i power on my notebook it starts without wifi connected. So despite It shows all wifi around modem when i type password to connect my home network it keeps "Can't connect this network" and again asks for password (Its something like Wifi authentication problem or password saving , i did't got actually ).I used usb wifi adapter but it works .Means connect to my network.I examine about it some says try forget and again type password some says reset router some says reset network config , I even reinstall my device adapter drive from official page even it did't worked.
So i only connect to my wifi on my computer via usb wifi adapter.It there aybody knows about how can i fix it?

```
  Not it connects sometimes UNSECURED WIFI Networks.But sometimes not.
```

Comment: Look in Control Panel, Device Manager. Are there any red or yellow marks on the Wireless Device?

Comment: Sure every driver installed.

Comment: It appears there may be some sort of hardware issue with the built in wireless device including not being seated properly or antenna wires needing re-seating

Comment: But why shows , and dont connect?I mean if it were like that it would never list available networks?AND I Add some note above text .It connect sometimes UNSECURE WIFI networks , which does't require any password.

Comment: The other possibility ( I have seen this ) is that the card is not completely compatible with your router. Try updating the firmware on the Router.

Comment: No.Does't connect any wifi .I have used with my router several years.Even I reset my OS it does't work.When Winodws 10 Boot menu ask for connect to wifi at reset im giving correct password , but says uncable to connect , after again I used USB Wifi adapter it worked..

Comment: The built in adapter must have a fault of som kind. There is no other answer given all your tests and the fact the USB wireless works fine.

Comment: I think like that really .I flushed DNS,ARP/Route table , Internet cache ,i do almost everthing.But nothing changed. .

Answer (score 0):

Background: Built in wireless adapter does not connect reliably.

Many tests tried including (but not limited to) re-installing the card and verifying all router connections and resetting the Operating System also.

Solution: Replace the card or simply continue with the USB wireless card which does work.

Comment: so you think my wifi adapter does't work anymor?

Comment: Yes. You have done so much including resetting the Operating System and we have worked together on all the tests that this is now most likely.  Not good news, I do understand.

Comment: I agree, it sounds like a bad WiFi card. It's rare to have issues like this with modern hardware, but it does happen.